# Custom IdempotentConsumer/Processor in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I want to perform custom logic in an IdempotentConsumer. I've extended the class and implemented the logic. How can I add this to my route?

Do I have to make my own Definition class? Do I add it as a Processor? How do I get the parameters passed to the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Well, custom consumer/producer could be little overkill. I think for some kind of custom logic is enough to do it trough processor or custom bean.

1.Bean

Look at [bean binding](https://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html) you can use [simple language](https://camel.apache.org/simple.html) to pass arguments to your method. It will looks like this:

```
.bean(OrderService.class, "doSomething(${body}, true)")

.to("bean:orderService?method=doSomething(null, true)")
```

2.Processor

You have to realize your classes should be **stateless** because of concurrent matter of camel framework. Your constructor should be empty and your variables final otherwise whole bunch of magic could happen. Everything you want to pass to your logic component/processor should be passed via **Exchange** object. You can store your variables in `getin()` or `getOut()` messages as headers or body or `Exchange` properties and pass it to next endpoint. The exchange will change dynamically as it flows trough you camel routes. It should be your one and only one mutable object.

Comment: I'm not looking to add any state, however I do want access to the internals of the IdempotentConsumer (the message ID and the repository).